# PostgreSQL dynamic fetch foward count value

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2, database-cursor

I have the following function used to retrieve a batch of Ids from a table.  This function is being used as the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses seem to offer poor performance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getBatch(_workloadId VARCHAR, _offSet INT, _limit INT)
  RETURNS SETOF NUMERIC AS $$
DECLARE 
    c SCROLL CURSOR FOR
      SELECT id FROM workload WHERE workload_id = $1 ORDER BY id ASC; 
BEGIN

OPEN c;
MOVE FORWARD $2 IN c; 
RETURN QUERY FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM c;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want the `FETCH FORWARD`*`count`* to be passed in as a parameter, but I'm unable to find a way to do this. Referencing $3 does not work, I've also tried the following:

```
EXECUTE 'RETURN QUERY FETCH FORWARD ' || $3 || ' FROM c;';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for your reply.  Sorry it's taken me so long to comment.  The requirement changed meaning that the problem became moot.  I appreciate the solutions you offered, however the `FETCH FORWARD count` did work other than the fact the `count` value couldn't be dynamic.  So `FETCH FORWARD 10` would happily return 10 results.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing [**SQL cursors**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) with [**PL/pgSQL cursors**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING), which are similar but not the same. In particular, there is no `FETCH FORWARD` *`count`* in PL/pgSQL:

> The ***`direction`*** clause can be any of the variants allowed in the
> SQL [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) command except the ones that can fetch more than one
> row; namely, it can be `NEXT`, `PRIOR`, `FIRST`, `LAST`, `ABSOLUTE`
> ***`count`***, `RELATIVE` ***`count`***, `FORWARD`, or `BACKWARD`.

In PL/pgSQL you can only fetch *one* row at a time and process (or return) it.
There is also a [disclaimer in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html):

> **Note**: This page describes usage of cursors at the SQL command level. If you are trying to use cursors inside a PL/pgSQL function,
> the rules are different.

You could open that cursor in PL/pgSQL and [loop to return rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP). But that's only relevant if you want to fetch multiple distinct pieces from a big cursor to save overhead. Else a plain `FOR` loop (with automatic cursor) or a simple `SELECT` with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` are certainly faster. Cursors are primarily meant to be returned to and used by the client:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getbatch_ref(_cursor refcursor, _workload_id text)
  RETURNS refcursor
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   OPEN $1 SCROLL FOR
   SELECT id
   FROM   workload
   WHERE  workload_id = $2
   ORDER  BY id; 

   RETURN $1;
END
$func$;
```

You can use this function in SQL:

```sql
BEGIN;
SELECT getbatch_ref('c', 'foo');
MOVE  FORWARD 10 IN c; 
FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM c;

ROLLBACK; -- or COMMIT;
```

You could also just use plain SQL:

```sql
BEGIN;
DECLARE c SCROLL CURSOR FOR
   SELECT id
   FROM   workload
   WHERE  workload_id = 'foo'
   ORDER  BY id; 

-- OPEN c; -- only relevant in plpgsql
-- The PostgreSQL server does not implement an OPEN statement for cursors;
-- a cursor is considered to be open when it is declared. 
MOVE  FORWARD 10 IN c; 
FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM c;

ROLLBACK; -- or COMMIT;
```